# Concat Two Strings then Convert to Date in Java

Tags: java, string, date, concatenation

I need to concat two strings together in Java and then format the string and make it a Date object.

The two strings that I have at the moment are `31/01/2012` and `20:00` and I want to do something like:

```
try {
  DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm");
  Date result = new Date();
  String tempDate = date + " " + f;
  result = formatter.parse(tempDate);
} catch (ParseException e) {
  ...etc
}
```

Can someone help me figure how to add the two strings together. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What is not working?Seems fine to me...

Comment: @PetrMensik yeah as people have suggested, it was a stupid mistake on my behalf with formatting the date from `-` to `/`

Comment: You don't need the "new Date()" up front since the formatter.parse() creates a new instance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your concatenation is fine. Yet it seems that your format is `"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"`

Answer (score 1):

The code looks good. 
Just correct the format 
it should be

> "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDateTime.of( 
    LocalDate.parse( 
        "31/01/2012" , 
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uuuu" ) 
    ) , 
    LocalTime.parse( "20:00" ) 
).atZone( ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) )
```

> 2012-01-31T20:00+01:00[Africa/Tunis]

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/nDfWhr).

## Using java.time

You are using troublesome old date-time classes, now supplanted by the java.time classes.

You need not concatenate the strings. Parse each, one as a [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) and one as a [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html).

```
DateTimeFormatter fDate = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uuuu" ) ;
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.format( "31/01/2012" , fDate ) ;

LocalTime lt = LocalTime.parse( "20:00" ) ; // Built-in formatter handles standard ISO 8601 formats.
```

You can combine those two parts into [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html). A `LocalDateTime` has no concept of [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) nor [offset-from-UTC](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=13&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiJjeWI7MPUAhVC3WMKHSUcAQUQFghkMAw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FUTC_offset&usg=AFQjCNFoBZgkAbu5VCeX8c7qDf4mNSfb5A&sig2=X0LDz3FcmSeNH63s4wLZTw).

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.of( ld , lt ) ;
```

We have no indication of offset-from-UTC nor time zone. So we do *not* have a specific moment, on an idea about *possible* moments. For example, 8 PM comes much earlier in New Zealand (`Pacific/Auckland`) than it does in India (`Asia/Kolkata`), and comes hours later in France (`Europe/Paris`).

To determine a specific moment, we must put that `LocalDateTime` in the context of a time zone. Perhaps you intended that moment for UTC.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = ldt.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

Or perhaps you meant that for Québec time.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone( z ) ;
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).